# Помогите с многостраничным магазином discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Попробовал соединить 2 кода и сделать магазин ролей многостраничным, но нужна помощь, хочу чтобы лимит ролей входящих в 1 страницу магазина были 5, а остальные уже на другой.

Вот код магазина ролей:

```
@client.command(aliases = ['магазин']) #неготово добавить несколько страниц или убрать роли 
async def __магазин(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    page1 = discord.Embed(title = 'Магазин ролей 1 страница')
    counter = 0
    for row in cursor.execute("SELECT role_id, cost FROM shop WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.guild.id)):
        if ctx.guild.get_role(row[0]) != None:
            counter += 1
            page1.add_field(
                value = f"{ctx.guild.get_role(row[0]).mention}" ,
                name = f"**Роль** № {counter} **Стоимость** {row[1]} <:crowcoin1:870664409884803082>",
                inline = False
            )
        else:
            pass
    page2 = discord.Embed(title = 'Магазин ролей 2 страница')
    counter = 0
    for row in cursor.execute("SELECT role_id, cost FROM shop WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.guild.id)):
        if ctx.guild.get_role(row[0]) != None:
            counter += 1
            page2.add_field(
                value = f"{ctx.guild.get_role(row[0]).mention}" ,
                name = f"**Роль** № {counter} **Стоимость** {row[1]} <:crowcoin1:870664409884803082>",
                inline = False
            )
        else:
            pass
    page3 = discord.Embed(title = 'Магазин ролей 3 страница')
    counter = 0
    for row in cursor.execute("SELECT role_id, cost FROM shop WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.guild.id)):
        if ctx.guild.get_role(row[0]) != None:
            counter += 1
            page3.add_field(
                value = f"{ctx.guild.get_role(row[0]).mention}" ,
                name = f"**Роль** № {counter} **Стоимость** {row[1]} <:crowcoin1:870664409884803082>",
                inline = False
            )
        else:
            pass
    pages = [page1, page2, page3]
    message = await ctx.send(embed = page1)
    await message.add_reaction('⏮')
    await message.add_reaction('◀')
    await message.add_reaction('▶')
    await message.add_reaction('⏭')

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author

    i = 0
    reaction = None

    while True:
        if str(reaction) == '⏮':
            i = 0
            await message.edit(embed = pages[i])
        elif str(reaction) == '◀':
            if i > 0:
                i -= 1
                await message.edit(embed = pages[i])
        elif str(reaction) == '▶':
            if i < 2:
                i += 1
                await message.edit(embed = pages[i])
        elif str(reaction) == '⏭':
            i = 2
            await message.edit(embed = pages[i])
        
        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout = 30.0, check = check)
            await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
        except:
            break

    await message.clear_reactions()
```

Вот весь код без магазина ролей:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
 
import sqlite3
from config import settings
from Cybernator import Paginator as pag
 
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['PREFIX'])
client.remove_command('help')
 
connection = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
 
 
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name TEXT,
        id INT,
        cash BIGINT,
        rep INT,
        lvl INT,
        server_id INT
    )""")
 
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shop (
        role_id INT,
        id INT,
        cost BIGINT
    )""")
 
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1, {guild.id})")
            else:
                pass
 
    connection.commit()
    print('client connected')
 
 
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1, {member.guild.id})")
        connection.commit()
    else:
        pass
 

 
@client.command(aliases = ['balance', 'cash'])
async def __balance(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Баланс пользователя **{ctx.author}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]} :leaves:**"""
        ))
        
    else:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Баланс пользователя **{member}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(member.id)).fetchone()[0]} :leaves:**"""
        ))  
 
 
@client.command(aliases = ['award'])
async def __award(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, amount: int = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, укажите пользователя, которому желаете выдать определенную сумму")
    else:
        if amount is None:
            await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, укажите сумму, которую желаете начислить на счет пользователя")
        elif amount < 1:
            await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, укажите сумму больше 1 :leaves:")
        else:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash + {} WHERE id = {}".format(amount, member.id))
            connection.commit()
 
            await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
 
 
@client.command(aliases = ['take'])
async def __take(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, amount = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, укажите пользователя, у которого желаете отнять сумму денег")
    else:
        if amount is None:
            await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, укажите сумму, которую желаете отнять у счета пользователя")
        elif amount == 'all':
            cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = {} WHERE id = {}".format(0, member.id))
            connection.commit()
 
            await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
        elif int(amount) < 1:
            await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, укажите сумму больше 1 :leaves:")
        else:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash - {} WHERE id = {}".format(int(amount), member.id))
            connection.commit()
 
            await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
 
 
@client.command(aliases = ['add-shop'])
async def __add_shop(ctx, role: discord.Role = None, cost: int = None):
    if role is None:
        await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, укажите роль, которую вы желаете внести в магазин")
    else:
        if cost is None:
            await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, укажите стоимость для даннойй роли")
        elif cost < 0:
            await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, стоимость роли не может быть такой маленькой")
        else:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO shop VALUES ({}, {}, {})".format(role.id, ctx.guild.id, cost))
            connection.commit()
 
            await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
 
 
@client.command(aliases = ['remove-shop'])
async def __remove_shop(ctx, role: discord.Role = None):
    if role is None:
        await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, укажите роль, которую вы желаете удалить из магазина")
    else:
        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM shop WHERE role_id = {}".format(role.id))
        connection.commit()
 
        await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
 
 
@client.command(aliases = ['buy', 'buy-role'])
async def __buy(ctx, role: discord.Role = None):
    if role is None:
        await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, укажите роль, которую вы желаете приобрести")
    else:
        if role in ctx.author.roles:
            await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, у вас уже имеется данная роль")
        elif cursor.execute("SELECT cost FROM shop WHERE role_id = {}".format(role.id)).fetchone()[0] > cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]:
            await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, у вас недостаточно средств для покупки данной роли")
        else:
            await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
            cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash - {} WHERE id = {}".format(cursor.execute("SELECT cost FROM shop WHERE role_id = {}".format(role.id)).fetchone()[0], ctx.author.id))
            connection.commit()
 
            await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
 
 
@client.command(aliases = ['rep', '+rep'])
async def __rep(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, укажите участника сервера")
    else:
        if member.id == ctx.author.id:
            await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, вы не можете указать смого себя")
        else:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET rep = rep + {} WHERE id = {}".format(1, member.id))
            connection.commit()
 
            await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
 
 
@client.command(aliases = ['leaderboard', 'lb'])
async def __leaderboard(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Топ 10 сервера')
    counter = 0
 
    for row in cursor.execute("SELECT name, cash FROM users WHERE server_id = {} ORDER BY cash DESC LIMIT 10".format(ctx.guild.id)):
        counter += 1
        embed.add_field(
            name = f'# {counter} | `{row[0]}`',
            value = f'Баланс: {row[1]}',
            inline = False
        )
 
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
 
 
client.run(settings['TOKEN'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше использовать `пагинатор`, готовый или написать свой.

Не помню как юзать модуль sqlite3, но не суть

```
@client.command(aliases = ['магазин']) #неготово добавить несколько страниц или убрать роли 
async def __магазин(ctx):
    def list_slice(lst, count):
        gen = (lst[count*i:count*(i+1)] for i in range(len(lst) // count + 1))
        return list(filter(bool, gen))

    await ctx.message.delete()
    for rows in cursor.execute(f"SELECT role_id, cost FROM shop WHERE id = {ctx.guild.id}"):
        msg = ""
        embeds = []
        for row in list_slice(rows, кол-во предметов на странице):
            if ctx.guild.get_role(row[0]):
                msg += f"**Роль** № {counter} **Стоимость** {row[1]} <:crowcoin1:870664409884803082>"
        embeds.append(discord.Embed(description=msg))
    #paginator = ...
    #paginator.start()
```